# Excluding dates from Linq Query in MVC .net application

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Within an asp.net MVC app, I'm trying to find rooms which have a guest/client, where the guest is leaving before a certain date.

The Client model class has foreign key, RoomId:

```
public class Room
{
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Room Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }
    public List<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Arrival { get; set; }
    public DateTime Departure { get; set; }
    public Room Room { get; set; }
}
```

My current Linq query is:

```
from r in Rooms
where r.Disabled == false
//where r.Clients.Departure<=DateTime.Parse("2012-07-01")
select new
  {
    r.Name,
    r.Disabled
  }
```

The commented line: //where r.Clients.Departure..... brings up the following error in LinqPad:

> 'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Departure' and no extension method 'Departure'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet' could be found
>   (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)

Is there any way, within Linq, that I can run this query, to exclude the Departure date where clause?

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your comment, this one should do what you need

```
&& r.Clients.All(client => client.Departure<=DateTime.Parse("2012-07-01"))
```

Edit :

Maybe declare the DateTime to compare out of the query

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse("2012-07-01");
```

and

```
&& r.Clients.All(client => client.Departure<=dt)
```

Comment: Hi - I want to return a list of rooms, where all associated guests/clients have departed before a specific date - that way, I know the room is free, and we can allocate another person to it, who will need it for a length of time.  Then when allocated, their departure date will then also exclude that room, before a specific date. This is a recovery unit, where stays may be long term, and rooms may be geographically separated - so I need to ensure only free rooms are listed as available to the administrators.  Thank you, Mark

Comment: Thanks @Raphaeul-Althaus and Dommer - I really appreciate your help with this.  Mark

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change the `Room` reference in `Client` to be virtual and the `Client` reference in `Room` to be a virtual `ICollection`? That should help the EF to make the connection.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg715120(v=vs.103).aspx or here for something from Julia Lerman on the subject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx

This should enable you to re-add the commented-out clause and it should work.

**EDIT: Actually the commented out bit should change in line with Raphaël Althaus's correction.**

I reckon a combination of what I and Raphaël have suggested is the best approach.

Like this

```
public class Room
{
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Room Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Arrival { get; set; }
    public DateTime Departure { get; set; }
    public virtual Room Room { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I wonder why I got downvoted. I think what I've written is correct, isn't it?

Comment: (not the downvoter, but) : problem is that Clients is a list. That list (as a list) has no Departure property. Your correction is fine... but it's not the real problem.

Comment: But if he's using Entity Framework and it's making the join automatically (which it will), then Clients shouldn't be a list. It should be a `virtual ICollection<Client>` which will fix the issue!

Comment: Hi - I didn't downvote either - but I'm bowing to your obvious higher knowledge than mine - Raphael - when you say absolutely not, are you disagreeing with Dommers suggestion?  I'm new to LINQ, and hoping to use best practice from the start, rather than fudge things.  Thanks a lot, Mark

Comment: @Mark: What happens if you use your original query (uncomment the line causing an error) with my changes to your `Client` and `Room` classes? This is how I've done this kind of thing when using EntityFramework in production code and it should work. The links I have given you to MSDN and Julia Lerman should corroborate this and I reckon it's the correct way to do it.

Comment: @MarkTait : I say that Dommer's suggestion is wrong, as Clients HAS NO property Departure. Clients is a list of Client, it's not a Client. So you're code would not even compile. You can make the corrections that Dommer pointed (this is a good idea), but this won't change anything in your query : it won't compile. See my answer, and look at the difference.

Comment: @Dommer Again no your correction is fine, but: create a Console app. Paste the class code, paste the query (with a list of Room, instead of an EF context, doesn't change anything in this case). It will just never compile.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: Aaah, I see. Sorry, I misread the originally commented out bit of code. Apologies :-$ i will update my answer so it at least makes sense... ;-)

Comment: @Dommer Ahhh, I was sure we would finally agree ;)

Comment: Hi @Dommer - I plus oned your answer, as it is extremely helpful - sorry I can't plus it again, and apologies someone downed it in the first place!!! cheers, Mark

Comment: Thanks Mark, you should +1 Raphael's answer as well as accepting it (which you've already done) - I did!